# What, exactly, is needed for "margin: 0 auto;" to work?

Tags: css

I know that setting `margin: 0 auto;` on an element is used to centre it (left-right). However, I know that the element and its parent must meet certain criteria for the auto margin to work, and I can never seem to get the magic right.

So my question is simple: what CSS properties have to be set on an element and its parent in order for `margin: 0 auto;` to left-right centre the child?

Comment: this never seems to work properly for me in IE... so I'm curious about this too.

Comment: @Mark: IE will handle `margin: 0 auto;` correctly only in standards mode so you need a doctype (as if one wasn't needed before).

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

1. The element must be block-level, e.g. `display: block` or `display: table`
2. The element must not float
3. The element must not have a fixed or absolute position<sup>1</sup>

Off the top of other people's heads:

4. The element must have a `width` that is not `auto`<sup>2</sup>

Note that **all** of these conditions must be true of the element being centered for it to work.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>There is one exception to this: if your fixed or absolutely positioned element has `left: 0; right: 0`, [it *will* center with auto margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261595/why-does-position-absolute-left-0-right-0-width-xypx-margin-0-auto-ac/29261847#29261847).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Technically, `margin: 0 auto` does work with an auto width, but the auto width takes precedence over the auto margins, and the auto margins are zeroed out as a result, making it seem as though they "don't work".</sub>

Comment: add the fixed width and you got the perfect answer

Comment: I miss the `ol start` attribute (and it's not possible to pull off in Markdown) :(

Comment: Cheers, that does seem to work. It's still hard to make the `li`s of a `ul` spread across it evenly, though, but I guess that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: This is bull.  I have an absolutely positioned element with margin:auto that is centered.  I set position:absolute;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0;margin:auto; and it gets centered.  Here's the snag, if the element to be centered is an img or canvas, for example, then this works with simply having HTML width/height attributes set.  However, if it's a DIV, then HTML width/height are insufficient, and you must have CSS width/height set.  Extremely bizarre and inconsistent behavior.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/31928807/88409

Comment: @Triynko: Neither the question nor my answer ever said anything about HTML presentational attributes (the question isn't even tagged [html]!), so I'm not sure what exactly you're calling bull on. Anyway, while every element that can be targeted with CSS can have the CSS width and height properties, not all HTML elements can have the corresponding presentational attributes, and the reason for that is simply that it doesn't make sense to have them on certain HTML elements.

Comment: @Triynko: So I came back to your comment, and I finally realized you're probably calling bull on the note about absolutely positioned elements. [I do stand corrected on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261595/why-does-position-absolute-left-0-right-0-width-xypx-margin-0-auto-ac/29261847#29261847) (half a year before your comment, oddly enough), and have edited my answer. Remember that this was off the top of my head at the time...

Comment: you could use ```width: fit-content;``` after you set ```margin: auto;```

Comment: Thanks. The "element must be block-level" always confuses me.

Comment: Are there any conditions where, despite all these conditions being met, it still doesn't work? Because I'm in that situation...

Answer (score 25):

Off the top of my head, it needs a `width`. You need to specify the width of the container you are centering (not the parent width).

Comment: Everything's coming off the top of our heads!

Answer (score 15):

Complete rule for CSS:

1. (`display: block` AND `width` not auto) OR `display: table`
2. `float: none`
3. `position: relative` OR `position: static`

OR

1. parent element with `display: flex`

Comment: position: static is also good.

Answer (score 8):

Off the top of my cat's head, make sure the `div` you're trying to center is not set to `width: 100%`.

If it is, then the rules set on the child divs are what will matter.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head, if the element is not a block element - make it so.

and then give it a width.

Answer (score 2):

It will also work with display:table - a useful display property in this case because it doesn't require a width to be set. (I know this post is 5 years old, but it's still relevant to passers-by ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Suggestion:

```
First: 
      1. Add display: block or table
      2. Add position: relative
      3. Add width:(percentage also works fine)
Second: 
      if above trick not works then you have to add float:none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go to this quick example I've created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNfWb/2/). Hopefull it's easy to understand. You can use a `wrapper` div with the width of the site to center align. The reason you must put `width` is that so browser knows you are not going for a liquid layout.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps interesting that you do not have to specify width for a `<button>` element to make it work - just make sure it has `display:block` : http://jsfiddle.net/muhuyttr/

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have a fixed width for your parent element, having your parent element with `display: flex` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

For anybody just now hitting this question, and not being able to fix `margin: 0 auto`, here's something I discovered you may find useful: a `table` element *with no specified width* must have `display: table` and *not* `display: block` in order for `margin: auto` to do work. This may be obvious to some, as the combination of `display: block` and the default `width` value will give a table which expands to fill its container, but if you *want* the table to take it's "natural" width *and* be centered, you need `display: table`

Comment: [That isn't true.](https://jsbin.com/cetivobaji/1/edit?html,css,output) (Although if you *just* give it `display: block` then it won't meet condition 4 of the accepted answer)

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the heads up. In my case, I _didn't_ want the table to fill the horizontal space (which would seem to obviate the whole discussion about `margin: 0 auto`) and I also _couldn't_ specify the width of the table, as its contents could have different widths. In this case, the only solution that works (i.e. renders the table the normal way but centers it) is _no_ width rule, `display: table` and `margin: 0 auto`