# Stuck in the middle

Tags: css

When should I use `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto` to center and when should I use `margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%`?

Maybe "auto" when I am centering something contained in another element & 50% when I am centering on the page?

Or I am I just hopelessly confused?

Comment: you can never use margin-left and margin-right simultaneously for better results. Better Use Div in the top and put text-align: center;

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or I am I just hopelessly confused?

Maybe :)

- `margin-left: 50%; margin-right: 50%` is not generally useful: http://jsfiddle.net/VcDYr/
- Where you might use `margin-left: 50%` is if you're centering like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VcDYr/1/
- To "center the page", you invariably want `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`. A shorter way to write this is `margin: 0 auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/VcDYr/2/

Consider that `div` is a block-level element.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

> auto - See the section on calculating
>   widths and margins for behavior.

Which leads to: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins

> Block-level, non-replaced elements in
>   normal flow
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
>
> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the edges of the containing block.

Answer (score 5):

`margin-left:50% ; margin-right:50%;` would imply that the item you are centering has no width.

For a block level element like a `div`, the best way to center it is:

```css
div.centered { margin: 0 auto; }
```

The 0 before the auto refers to top and bottom so that can be set to whatever you like. The important part is the `auto` which will cause the left and right margins to be automatically set and they will be equal regardless of how wide your element is.

Update: As pointed out by Phelios, a width should be specified for the div for this approach to work

Comment: given that you must specify width

Comment: "margin-left:50% ; margin-right:50%; would imply that the item you are centering has no width"

Comment: "margin-left:50% ; margin-right:50%; would imply that the item you are centering has no width" - does it?  2 possibilities: 1) that is true and the browser is forgiving, since submit buttons and text centered that way _are_ shown 2) the browser _first_ calculates the size of the item (submit button, text, etc) then sets the margins to 50% of whatever is left.  In either case, it seems to work, even if it is "wrong"

Answer (score 1):

To Center a div container you need to give it a width and a hight than you use

```css
#div {
   height: 700px;
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```