# CSS - align center

Tags: html, css

I'm finally trying to do away with tables and use CSS.

I have 3 DIVs that make up a three layered layout: header, body and footer. I'm now trying to overlay a 900px wide DIV on top of these layers, center aligned, which will hold some of my content and navigational buttons.

These are the 3 layers:

[image]

And this (done in Photoshop), is what I am trying to achieve but transparent to the eye:

[image]

My 3 base layers are coded like this:

```
<div id="main" style="width:100%; z-index:1; position:relative;">
    <div id="header" style="width:100%; height:175px; text-align:center; background:#151515; z-index:1;"></div>
    <div id="contents" style="width:100%; height:400px; position:relative; background:#FFF; z-index:1;"></div>
    <div id="footer" style="width:100%; height:200px; position:relative; background:#151515; z-index:1;"></div>
</div>
```

I did manage to get a new layer to sit on top but it wasn't center aligned. Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: A few tips:

1) By default DIVs are all 100% width unless told otherwise.

2) position:relative is used to set a new anchor point for absolutely-positioned children - you have none.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Diodeus, much appreciated. I removed the absolutely positioned children for this example, but useful to know width is 100% as default..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehting like this could help:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DSH5J/

Add:

```
<div id="square"></div>

#square {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: @ANeves - Could explain what you meant please?

Comment: That's not my code ANeves ;-) I just placed the square. He meant if you add text to the div with id #contents the text goes over the footer div. That's because you are working with absolute height (400px, 175px, 200px)

Comment: @daageu - do you know what he/she meant by that? Have I got something wrong in my original code?

Comment: @MartinG if it works for you it then works for you, great! :) But this is what I mean, look at the text: http://jsfiddle.net/DSH5J/10/

Comment: Ah that's okay, nothing is actually going in those base layers. I should re-id them as top, middle and bottom, instead of contents. All the content will be going in the the new top layer. I want the effect of full page (100% base layers) but content is restricted to 900px. If that makes any sense :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the width and set margin-left and margin-right to auto. That's for horizontal only, though. If you want both ways, you'd just do it both ways.

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: Oh yeah... see my own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way that I know of to centre a `div` of known width is to give it the following styles:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
width: 900px;
margin-left: -450px;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Putting my money where my mouth is": http://jsfiddle.net/YVmBU/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="contents-box">
        <div id="contents">
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>etc</p>
            <p>etc</p>
            <p>etc</p>
            <p>etc</p>
            <p>etc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    height:100px;
    background:#151515;
    z-index: -1;
}
#contents-box {
    border: dashed grey 1px; /* for understanding only, remove it in the end */
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    /* TODO: address min-height; try only one line of text. */
    /* fixed height would work too, but would not let the box stretch dynamically */
}
#contents {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: grey;
    z-index: 1;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    height:75px;
    background:#151515;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The only problem is with few text content: if min-height is used on #content, then the grey background does not stretch when there is few text; if a static height of N px is used, then the box does not stretch dinamically.

But if the two black bars merging when there is few content is not important, then ignore it.

---

Remove the grey dashed border and grey background; those are helpers - to know where each box is and understand what is happening.

By the way, the position: relative needs to be there on the `z-index: -1;` layers, otherwise the background does not go under. Read on position: this is because things in html have `position: static` by default, and z-index relies on position for its behaviour.
You can read about this in this page: http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp

Answer (score -1):

The only problem is with few text content: if min-height is used on #content, then the grey background does not stretch when there is few text; if a static height of N px is used, then the box does not stretch dinamically.

But if the two black bars merging when there is few content is not important, then ignore it.

Comment: This answer states what is wrong with the OP's code but does not provide an answer. In addition, this entire statement was stolen, word for word, from @ANeves answer below. -1, neither answers the question nor is your own answer.