# Aligning checkbox to center of td styling only checkbox?

Tags: css, checkbox, alignment, css-tables

I have a table that has particular rows containing checkboxes. I want to have these checkboxes aligned to center of their parent td's.
I know that I can achieve that by styling the parent td like that:

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I also know that I can easily achieve that with jQuery, but unfortunately, I cannot use jQuery.

The table is created through .NET and I cannot target the specific columns that contain checkboxes by giving a certain class.

I wonder if there is a way of styling the checkbox itself in order to align it to the center of it's parent td.

Something like:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it by set `display: block;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to `input[type=checkbox]`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jtmgrzej/1/)**

```
td {
    width: 100%;
    background: #EEE;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

**Solution 2:** **-** **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jtmgrzej/2/)**

Set `display: table;` or `display: flex;` to `input[type=checkbox]`

```
td {
    width: 100%;
    background: #EEE;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

**For More Info:**

> [What, exactly, is needed for “margin: 0 auto;” to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work)

Comment: `vertical-align` stops working if used with `margin: 0 auto;`.