# CSS container won't center

Tags: css, containers, center

I started writing my first website, and tried to center the container id in CSS using various methods found on the web (the most common of which being margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;) but it simply won't work, and I have no idea why, or what could I do about it (I know, I could make a table with three columns in the html file, but I don't want to mix and match tables and divs)

My code so far looks like this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
hello world!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
background-color:#FFF; 
}

#content {
width:980px;
background-color:#FCC;
position: absolute;
display:block;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
top: 0px;
bottom:0px;
align:center;
}
```

Comment: It will center if you remove the `position:absolute` and the position values...[**This might help**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution #1:

Replace `position: absolute;` with `position: relative;` in `#content`(CSS).

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xqcd91ch/) and [Full Screen View](http://jsfiddle.net/xqcd91ch/embedded/result/)**

```css
body, html {
    background-color:#FFF;
    height:100%;
}
#content {
    width:980px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#FCC;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">hello world!</div>
```

**More Info about `margin: 0 auto;` center to work:**

> **[What, exactly, is needed for `margin: 0 auto;` to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work)**

### Solution #2:

Add `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -490px;` (half width of `#content` div) to `#content`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk7d17h9/) and [Full Screen View](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk7d17h9/embedded/result/)**

```
#content {
    width: 980px;
    background-color: #FCC;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: -490px;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Container is in center you need to align text in the center if you want,

`align:center`

should be

```
text-align:center;
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarvrp95/)

Comment: I'm not the one... +1 for you and @KieranQuinn

Comment: I was still trying to center the div, lol (using notepad, so I didn't notice the mistake) thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to center the "Hello world" text?? If add

```
text-align: center;
```

Instead of

```
align:center;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't center something with `position: absolute;` on it, as far as I know. `position: absolute;` means, that the div has an absolute positioning to something.

If you want to center it, then you could wrap the container, in a div, with `position: relative;` on it, and then center that one.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  hello world!
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

With this CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
background-color:#FFF; 
}

#wrapper {
position: relative; /* Needs to be there, for the #content-container to know, 
what it's relative to. */
width: 100px; /* Needed as well */
display: block; /* For older browsers */
overflow: hidden; /* For older browsers */
margin: 0 auto 0; /* Adds the margin that centers it. */    
}

#content {
width:980px;
background-color:#FCC;
position: absolute;
display:block;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
top: 0px;
bottom:0px;
align:center;
}
```

The other way is just to replace this from your code:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom:0px;
```

With this:

```
position: relative;
```

Then your code should work as well...

Why do you want to center it, with `position: absolute;` ? Perhaps you want to achieve something, that there is another way of doing...

Comment: I wanted to make a container div with 100% height, no matter the length of the content it holds (and also, I figured that no space at the top and bottom of the page looks cool). It works using a wrapper, but then the effect I tried to obtain with the height disappears.