# Horizontal align SPAN inside div ( dynamic length , no text-align)?

Tags: html, css

I have this code :

```css
table
{
  border:solid 2px black;
  width:100%; /*must*/
}
td
{
  border:solid 2px red;
  padding:5px;
}

span
{
   border:solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
     <span  >There's already existing policy for : fugfuj tyutyuty</span>
      </td>
  </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I want to align the `span` to the center of `TD`.

I can do `text-align:center` but the `TD` is about to host future -injected-ajax -html so I don't want to touch it ( and start playing with remove/apply `text-align:center` ).

I could also do  `width:200px;display:block;` and then : `margin:0 auto;` but I dont know its length.

So before I go to JS solution :

**Question**

Is there any CSS only solution to center the span ?

related jsbin : http://jsbin.com/qokizunibifa/2/edit

Comment: Could you just make the span = 100% width, and text-align center on just the span? Or do you need the border around the span?

Comment: @StevenJeffries [did you try it](http://jsbin.com/qokizunibifa/4/edit)

Comment: Yes, I also added display: inline-block as well though. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e2jfytzs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: table;`  and `margin: 0 auto;` to `span` to horizontally center the `span` inside `div`

```css
table {
    border:solid 2px black;
    width:100%; /*must*/
}
td {
    border:solid 2px red;
    padding:5px;
}
span {
    border:solid 2px green;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>There's already existing policy for : fugfuj tyutyuty</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir `display: inline-block;` doesn't work with `margin: 0 auto;` to horizontally center elements but `display: table` does works.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Check this out - [What, exactly, is needed for “margin: 0 auto;” to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work)

Comment: As I said , I know that, ( meant block , not inline-block.) but then- i still need to know the width ( as i mentioned in the next line in my question)

Answer (score 1):

One more thing you can try is to play with `trasform: translateX(-50%)`:

```
span {
    border:solid 2px green;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/fegesusuqido/1/edit