# CSS width/height having different effect than HTML width/height attributes, depending on element type

Tags: html, css

For example, they cause completely different behavior in regards to auto margins.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1rk46xy/

```
<style>
.fixed {
    display:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
.centered {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
</style>
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="centered" style="width:100px;height:30px;" width="200" height="30">
        CENTERED
    </div>
</div>
```

It has a fixed element to fill the viewport, and inside that there's some centered text.  In my actual web app, this is a loading indicator that's supposed to be centered above content.  In order for margin:auto to work, the centered element needs to have top/right/bottom/left all set to zero and it needs to have a width and height. (Note: I'm explicitly avoiding the alternative centering method of using a top/left:50%, because it requires a hard-coded negative half-offset of the size, whereas this method will work for any size object).

Notice in the fiddle how the div element with text is centered.  Now, remove the style attribute that sets the width/height and leave only the HTML width/height attributes on the centered div.  The div element is no longer centered.

Furthermore, if you replace the div with an img, then HTML width/height attribute ARE sufficient to center it.  What is going on here?  Why the difference in CSS vs HTML attributes and between DIV and IMG tags?  This occurs regardless of whether these elements are block or inline (e.g. it uses absolute positioning anyway).

Comment: inline styles ALWAYS override styles defined elsehwere. and your `#centered` element is `position: absolute`, which removes it from the document for positioning/sizing calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that `div` elements don't have `height` and `width` attributes. If you specify those attributes in the markup, they are completely ignored. You can only size a div through CSS styles.

`img` elements on the other hand, do have those attributes.

See [div](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html#div) vs [img](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html#img).