# Can't center content using margin

Tags: html, css

Guys I am facing a problem:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS</title>
        <meta http-equiv="author" content="@infinite"><!--Credits-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form >
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:black;
}
form{
    width:500px;
    border:solid 5px white;
}
input[type="submit"]{
    width:200px;
    border:solid 5px white;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-family:Impact,fantasy;
    font-size:300%;
    color:white;
    background-color:inherit;
    margin:300px auto 300px auto;
}
```

I want to centralize the submit button in the form, but it still sticks to the left side of the form. The "auto" in the margin for the submit button is not working.

Please help..

Comment: just a text-align center to the form will do it!

Comment: But if I want to do it using the margin property, can I do it?

Comment: yes you can, I added the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpEdmE)

If you want the `margin: 0 auto` method to work, the element must be a block, so adding `display: block` to the submit button does the trick.

Referring from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955135/320946) it's good to know that if you want `margin: 0 auto` to work:

> - The element must display: block
> - The element must not float
> - The element must not have a fixed or absolute position
> - The element must have a width that is not auto

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @Sohail

Comment: sure man, I edited the answer and added some reference on how margin: 0 auto work as well

Answer (score 0):

you can try add this in form:

```
form{
  width:500px;
  border:solid 5px white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the input button's style:

```
display:block;
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto;` center horizontally only when

1. Display is `block` (or `table`)
2. Element is not floating
3. Width should not be auto or 100%

So, to solve your problem, add

```
input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
}
```

as `input` is displayed `inline` by default.