# CSS Images don't horizontally center on media query

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the image and its description in block form when the website has been shortened. I thought that setting `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, as well as setting `display` to `block` would center any image.

http://jsfiddle.net/8r5u22dm/

*HTML*

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="post-container">                
       <div class="post-thumb"><img src="img/flight_sun.png" id="first_image"/></div>
       <div class="post-content"><h1>Boeing 747</h1><p>             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed aliquam eros, vel ultricies eros. Donec fermentum quis lacus quis lacinia. Quisque imperdiet, orci quis ultrices accumsan, sapien libero venenatis risus, in bibendum magna orci at ex. Ut lobortis, lorem id malesuada mollis, turpis ex finibus ipsum, sit amet semper est erat quis lorem. Nullam eu molestie eros, et ultricies magna. Mauris in eros condimentum, vehicula enim ac, scelerisque lorem. Cras commodo turpis viverra, vestibulum massa vitae, rutrum turpis. Sed lobortis elit quis ipsum molestie tincidunt.</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-container">                
       <div class="post-thumb"><img src="img/flight_cloud.png" /></div>
       <div class="post-content"><h1>Sukhoi Su-35</h1><p>               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed aliquam eros, vel ultricies eros. Donec fermentum quis lacus quis lacinia. Quisque imperdiet, orci quis ultrices accumsan, sapien libero venenatis risus, in bibendum magna orci at ex. Ut lobortis, lorem id malesuada mollis, turpis ex finibus ipsum, sit amet semper est erat quis lorem. Nullam eu molestie eros, et ultricies magna. Mauris in eros condimentum, vehicula enim ac, scelerisque lorem. Cras commodo turpis viverra, vestibulum massa vitae, rutrum turpis. Sed lobortis elit quis ipsum molestie tincidunt.</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-container">                
       <div class="post-thumb"><img src="img/flight_clear.png" /></div>
       <div class="post-content"><h1>F-22 Raptor</h1><p>                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed aliquam eros, vel ultricies eros. Donec fermentum quis lacus quis lacinia. Quisque imperdiet, orci quis ultrices accumsan, sapien libero venenatis risus, in bibendum magna orci at ex. Ut lobortis, lorem id malesuada mollis, turpis ex finibus ipsum, sit amet semper est erat quis lorem. Nullam eu molestie eros, et ultricies magna. Mauris in eros condimentum, vehicula enim ac, scelerisque lorem. Cras commodo turpis viverra, vestibulum massa vitae, rutrum turpis. Sed lobortis elit quis ipsum molestie tincidunt.</p></div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.content {
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.content p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

/* Decrease the width of description */

@media screen and (max-width: 1175px) {
    .post-content {
        width: 470px;
    }
}

/* Second decrease the width of description */
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .post-content {
        width: 410px;
    }
}

/* Collapse into block formation */
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) {
    .post-content {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 300px;
    }

    .post-thumb {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .post-thumb img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
.container img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 32px;
    border-radius: 200px;
}

.post-container{
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;  
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.post-thumb img {
    float: left;
    clear:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background: red;
}

.post-content {
    float:right;
    width: 618px;
}

.content h1 {
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Set maximum width for navigation */
@media screen and (max-width: 340px) {
    header nav a {
        padding: 0 0.4em;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .content {
        text-align: justify;
    }
}
```

Comment: img { max-width:100%; height:auto} can you try it on img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work), for `margin: auto` to work your element must not have an absolute or fixed position (your images have absolute positioning) and they must not float (your images have `float: left`). If you remove those properties from your images they will be centered.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, I removed those properties from your jsfiddle and here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/1rtgvvqw/1/ (they are not in the same place but you can move the elements with position relative and with margins/paddings)