# Container not taking an auto margin

Tags: html, css, position

I am having a difficult time with a margin issue. Basically I have 4 boxes displayed inline.

I have the boxes themselves and then an internal container `.connect-box-wrap`. What I am trying to do is to get the horizontal margin for the `.connect-box-wrap` to be auto, so the start of the content is around the middle point of the box, making the `#contact-connect` appear more centered. Right now it looks as if the internal container is aligned left and not taking the `margin: 0 auto;`.

I am wanting the text to still be aligned left...I just want the internal container to have the horizontal auto margin.

Any ideas?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bm4jpwh1/)

Here is what it looks like now (paint image showing borders, if it had them).

[image: boxes now]

What I want this to look like is this:

[image: I want it to look like this]

This is a summary of the code, see the fiddle for the full code for all four boxes.

```
#contact-connect {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 10%;
    padding: 80px 0;
}
#contact-connect-box-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
.contact-connect-box {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 60px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    opacity: 0;
    transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
}
.connect-box-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="contact-connect">
        <div id="contact-connect-box-container">
            <div class="contact-connect-box">
                <div class="connect-box-wrap">
                <h2 class="contact-connect-title">A</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description"><a href="tel:3304888300">555.555.5555</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a width to the `.connect-box-wrap`, such as `width:80%`.  Otherwise it will default to 100% width and the `margin:0 auto` won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

To use `margin: 0 auto;` when centering elements, there are a few things that are required as outlined in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955135/2106563

> The element must display: block
>
> The element must not float
>
> The element must not have a fixed or absolute position
>
> The element must have a width that is not auto

So the only thing missing in your implementation is setting the width. You can set it to a percentage less than 100% and you should notice a change that you're looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/bm4jpwh1/2/

Answer (score 1):

`Margin: 0 auto` only works if the element has the width set. Plus the element can't be `display: inline` or `display:block`.

An alternative would be to set the element to `display: inline-block` and set the parent with `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 0):

add to #contact-connect text align center  and give to .contact-connect-box text align left.

```
#contact-connect {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 10%;
    padding: 80px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-connect-box {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 60px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    opacity: 1;
    transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
  text-align: left;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bm4jpwh1/1/)

Comment: This is centering the text. I want to leave the text aligned left. Just to essentially center the internal container,.

Comment: its not horizontaly? http://prntscr.com/bd5dvh ? you can add only text align center to all.

Comment: I update your fiddle. I give all the item 20% so you can see it horizontali alignment to center: https://jsfiddle.net/bm4jpwh1/1/  @Becky