# How to a center a div on resize

Tags: html, css

I have looked at the already asked questions and tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to be working for me. I have a div, with multiple div's inside of it, and I cannot get it to center in the middle of the page on resize

This is the parent div which contains multiple others

```
<div id="showme" class="newmodal" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; 
    max-width: 561px; left: 700px; top: 263px; display: none;">
```

This is the css for the div

```
.newmodal {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;   /* our page width */
    min-width: 500px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Sorry if I am being really stupid, very new to this. I have tried removing the left and top inline styles but nothing is working.

EDIT

I forgot to mention that this div is being hidden and unhidden using a button so I am not sure if that changes any of the current answers.

Comment: try to don't mix `style` attributes and `class`es and post working jsfiddle for us please

Comment: Could you add bigger chunks of source code? both `HTML` and `CSS`.

Comment: "resize" do you mean browser zoom?

Comment: @Ivan i think this is about resize event

Comment: but he didn't mention using JS? It's quite unclear to me

Comment: I mean resizing the browser to make it smaller^^

Comment: Yes that's what I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.newmodal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 900px;
  /* our page width */
  min-width: 500px;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div id="showme" class="newmodal">Some content</div>
```

It will center `div` vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `div` tag. Why use `width,max-width,min-width`? Try the following code:

```css
.newmodal {
  background: red;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="showme" class="newmodal"></div>
```

Comment: There are multiple divs inside, the div tag is closed but it;s too much code to put here

Comment: but don't have any problem, if you add some divs inside div 'newmodel'. give me inside code.

Answer (score 0):

I created this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/) that you can use to look at.  Try using something like this:

```
.newmodal {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Remove all of your styling from your `HTML` because you had some contradicting styles going on between the `CSS` and `HTML` you provided.

```
<div id="showme" class="newmodal">
   <!--Some added data-->
</div>
```

Remember also that in order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work, the element must be `block` style, it can't `float`, it can't be `fixed` or `absolute`, and a `width` that is not `auto`.  Found this information from this post: [What, exactly, is needed for "margin: 0 auto;" to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work)

**Edit:**

So if you are using `jQuery` and you want to make it appear and disappear,  you can do something like this:

```
$(".newmodal div").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

The only problem with this is making the element reappear. But I'm not sure what your entire project looks like but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this div is being hidden and unhidden using a button so I am not sure if that changes any of the current answers.

Comment: Are you using `javascript/jQuery`? @AshleyBlyth

Comment: Yes I am, to hide and unhide the div

Comment: @AshleyBlyth Added some code to help make an element disappear on click using `jQuery`.  It's not a perfect solution to your problem but it may steer you the right way.  Check documentation on `toggle()` as well, lots of examples out there. Hope I helped, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
  
#container {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid blue 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.newmodal {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding:7px; 
  width: 50%;
  background:#222;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="newmodal">Some content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this div is being hidden and unhidden using a button so I am not sure if that changes any of the current answers.

Answer (score -1):

1st the css part of "margin: 0 auto" and "width 50%" should be for the child div and not the parent.

2nd you can make your life much easier my moving to flexbox which does all that automatically.

See https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: but there are multiple child divs.

Comment: So use flexbox.