# How to let the div

Tags: css, less

I use the bellow less code to let the `con-order` width 80%:

```
.con-order {

    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
```

the html code is like bellow:

```
<div class="con-order">
    <div class="alert">
      <Alert type="warning" show-icon closable>
    ...
```

it bellow like this, I want the content move center.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I tried use `text-align: center;` but the content become odd.

It become like this, I don't want this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I want all move to center, not all content align center.

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `margin: 0 auto` is what does the actual centering of your div.

It will make the element center horizontally and it works without setting a specific width.

```
.con-order {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine for you.

```
.con-order {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
```