# How to center amp-img with responsive layout

Tags: amp-html

The following code does not work.  If would work if the layout were fixed.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <amp-img style="max-width: 640px;"  width="640" height="480" layout="responsive" src="~/Content/images/foo.JPG" />
</div>
```

Please note style="max-width: 640px;" used to prevent this image from filling the width when the window is wide enough.

Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your image wrapped in a `div` which is a good start. Not sure specifically how your page is set-up, but applying a margin of 0 auto to the `div` worked for me.

[Here's a pretty good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work) of `margin: 0 auto;` and why it may or may not work for centering.

```css
div.img-wrapper {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <amp-img src="/img/amp.jpg" width="640" height="200" layout="responsive" alt="AMP"></amp-img>
</div>
```

You can test it out [here](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-img%2Fsource%2F&mode=Custom&width=1920&height=1080) if you want to play around with it.

Comment: it works.  Thanks a lot.  I do not need to set max-width for the amp-img with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Craig Scott approach and idea. I only succeeded when I wrote the AMP image code for centering the image as follows.

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<amp-img src="https://jomutech.com/dispJomutechIcon.png height="50" width="250" layout="responsive" alt="Logo">
</amp-img>
</div>

<style amp-custom>
  div.img-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```