# What is the best way to center a div inside another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have so far been trying to create a basic website layout shown in this picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtNe4.jpg

It includes a grey background, with a centered div inside with a white background. With centered an image to the left and text etc to the right.

I am a large advocate for twitter bootstrap, so far I have implemented this. (React style)

```
            <div class="container-fluid" style={{
                'background-color' : 'rgb(224,225,226)',
                'height' : '40vh'
            }}>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1 text-center"> Test </div>

                    <div class="col-10 text-center" style={{
                        'height' : '30vh',
                        'background-color' : 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                        'margin-top' : '5vh'
                    }}>

                    centered

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-1 text-center">test</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So far it half ways. But honestly I kind of gave us because it's turned into a nested mess. With website development I always know their is a bigger way, so I come here for people to roast my attempt so far and could give me in a proper way of reaching my goal.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your content at all :O Can you properly as your question in the content part? Please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is you want people to evaluate your code.

Comment: @jdc91 I thought to accomplish my goal I had to center a div inside a div twice, is there a better route?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some ideas of how you can achieve it.

https://codepen.io/Warisara-L/pen/wOMxwR

```
// HTML
<div class="wrapper" id="solution-1">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
</div>

// SCSS
#solution-1 {
  display: grid;
  .inner {
    margin: auto;
  }
}

#solution-2 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#solution-3 {
  position: relative;
  .inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

#solution-4 {
  display: flex;
  .inner {
    margin: auto;
  }
}

#solution-5 {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#solution-6 {
  position: relative;
  .inner {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}

#solution-7 {
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

#solution-8 {
  display: flex;
  .inner {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Have a good day sir :)

Comment: Nice answer, but I found this the most useful.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 1):

## With FlexBox

With `display: flex;` you can specify the properties `justify-content` and `align-items` to `center` in order to center child elements both horizontally and vertically.

When a `display: flex` element is a row (`flex-direction: row;`) `justify-content` will handle horizontal positioning while `align-items` handles vertical positioning. When `flex-direction` is set to `column`, `justify-content` and `align-items` meanings are swapped.

Example:

```
.parent-element {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction defaults to row */

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

## With CSS Grid

You can utilize the property [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) to center the children of a grid. You should be aware, however, that `place-items` is not currently supported on all browsers.

Example:

```
.parent-element {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

## Margin auto

Sometimes you can utilize the `auto` value for the `margin` property to push an element towards the center.

Be sure to check out this post that explains [what is needed for `margin: auto;` to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work).

Example:

```
.child-element {
  /* top right bottom left -- all set to auto */
  margin: auto;
}
```

## Absolute positioning with a transform

You can position an item in the center of the screen by setting the `position` property to `absolute` (this will take it out of the normal document flow). Then, you can use the properties `left` and `top` to move the element down and to the right `50%`.

Once it's pushed `50%` we need to move it back half the width/height of the element, we can do that with a `translate` inside the property `transform`.

Example:

```
.child-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  /* translate(<x value>, <y value>) */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

#### Disclaimer:

This is not advised for elements that are a part of your normal document flow as they will most likely overlap other elements. It's great for modals though.

Comment: Well explanation, i prefer flex or grid system than margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the css `margin: 0 auto` in your inner div that you want to center.