# Why are the Margins within react not working correctly?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to understand some functionality of margins within React and still newbie with react. Currently, I have a `render` method that has some JSX/HTML. I'm trying to use CSS to style it better but have some questions regarding the code.

1. In the CSS, I had `Buttons` with `Margin: auto;` to center the elements within the container `NavBar` but it is not working. But when I have `text-align` in the `.NavBar` it works. Why is that? I thought it would work within Buttons because it will center relative to its parent container -> `NavBar`.

2.In `.NavBar`, when I have height `20%` for example, it does not change unless I hard code in pixels. Since NavBar is the child of the main `App.js`, wouldn't it work in relative to the App file?

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavBar} from './NavBar/NavBar';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="AppMain">
      <NavBar/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
.AppMain{
    height: 100%;
}
```

NavBar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './NavBar.css';

export class NavBar extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="NavBar">
                <button className="Buttons">About</button>
                <button className="Buttons">Contact</button>
                <button className="Buttons">Info</button>
                <button className="Buttons">Home</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

NavBar.css:

```
.NavBar{
    background-color: black;
    height: 20%;
}

.NavBar .Buttons{
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `<div>` that wraps all the buttons together and just put `margin: auto;` on that `div`, and you can remove the `margin:auto;` from the buttons.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have ```NavBar``` for that

Comment: But I assume you want `NavBar` to take the entire width, correct?

Comment: Yes for the width but even using it for height using ```%``` rather than pixels does not work.

Comment: That's why you need another `div` to just wrap the buttons and keep them in the center.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant with your last comment.

Comment: Oh i understand. I apologize I confused ClassName with div

Comment: No problem. You may also need to add `position:relative;` for the margin auto to work.

Comment: Regarding the App.js, if i wanted it to cover the whole space how would i approach that? i managed to get the NavBar to cover with % but the app when i have it in ```%``` it does not cover full page. Why is that?

Comment: A percent height only works within an element with a defined height (the parents height could be defined in px or % as long as it's parent has a defined height) except of the outermost element usually the `html` element which could its height defined in % cause it's parent is the window which has a defined height. So to your point I usually make my `html, body,.App` etc. 100% height and then I play around with the inside elements as needed.

Comment: Sorry for the long comment, hope all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`margin: auto;` only works if the width is specified and if the element is block-level. Look at [this answer to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955135) how centering with `margin: auto;` actually works.

The height doesn't work because you've set the height of the AppMain to 100% which will be calculated after everything is rendered onto the DOM. You're basically trying to calculate 20% of 100% of something that isn't calculated yet. Try explicitly setting the height of the AppMain and see what that does. [Relevant answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097).

Comment: Oh so for the App.js, it does not have a certain height so getting 100% of something that is ```null``` for example, it would do nothing. I heard that using vh is not safe to use. Is there a better way to do it or is it just based on opinion?

Comment: Why not just specify the height in `rem` or `px`? If you open the console and check how some websites define the nav height you'll get an idea. Stackoverflow sets it explicitly to 50px. css-tricks has it defined for each media query.

Answer (score 0):

The default display of the Button is inline-block. if you want to use margin: auto, You just need to change the display value to block