# CSS header with logo on the left and multiple paragraph on the far right

Tags: html, css

When my screen size is 768px and above, I am trying to align the logo to the left and multiple paragraph to the right. See the following pic. But I tried using float and display inline block but the the whole `top class` will align all the way to the left. It cannot be centralized, to all the gurus out there, please help as I am new in CSS. Thanks.

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

[image: Trying to achieve]

**WHAT I AM FACING**

[image: What I am facing]

**

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Open Sans;
}

.img-logo{
    width:300px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.img-banner{
    width:300px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.top{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top p {
    text-align: center;
}

.top p b {
    color: #053D66;
}


.header{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ol.s {
    list-style-type: upper-greek;
}

.img-footer{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* ----------- responsivity ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .top{
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block; 
    }

    .toright {
        float: right;
      }
      .toleft {
        float: left;
      }

    .img-banner{
        width:600px;
    }

    .header{
        width: 600px;
    }
    
    .wrapper{
        width: 600px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    <title>Updates</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="toleft">
            <img class="img-logo" src="http://www.talent-trust.com/documents/img/talent-trust.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="toright">
            <p style="margin:0px"><b style="color:#053D66;">E</b>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:info@talent-trust.com">info@talent-trust.com</a></p>
            <p style="margin:0px"><b style="color:#053D66;">T</b>&nbsp;0757 278 8418</p>
            <p style="margin:0px"><b style="color:#053D66;">W</b>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.talent-trust.com">www.talent-trust.com</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="header">
        <p><h2>COVID19 Medical Update for Missionaries, July 2020</h2></p>
        <p>Significant issues remain even if you have insurance</p>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**

Comment: Your `<div class="top">` is not centered, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: [according to this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work) your problem is that `margin: 0 auto;` does not work on inline-block.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please.

Comment: I posted an answer with the code working.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `display: inline-block` (since it doesn't work with `margin: 0 auto`). I also aligned your items using flexbox. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#justify-content) is some more information on flexblox.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.img-logo {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.img-banner {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.top {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top p {
  text-align: center;
}

.top p b {
  color: #053D66;
}

.header {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ol.s {
  list-style-type: upper-greek;
}

.img-footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* ----------- responsivity ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .top {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    
    /* Using flexbox instead: */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  /*
  .toright {
    float: right;
  }
  .toleft {
    float: left;
  }
  */
  .img-banner {
    width: 600px;
  }
  .header {
    width: 600px;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
  <title>Updates</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="toleft">
      <img class="img-logo" src="http://www.talent-trust.com/documents/img/talent-trust.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="toright">
      <p style="margin:0px"><b style="color:#053D66;">E</b>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:info@talent-trust.com">info@talent-trust.com</a></p>
      <p style="margin:0px"><b style="color:#053D66;">T</b>&nbsp;0757 278 8418</p>
      <p style="margin:0px"><b style="color:#053D66;">W</b>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.talent-trust.com">www.talent-trust.com</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="header">
    <p>
      <h2>COVID19 Medical Update for Missionaries, July 2020</h2>
    </p>
    <p>Significant issues remain even if you have insurance</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also relatively new to HTML and CSS, but one thing I would try, is to extend your .top to fill the entire width of the screen. This way float: right; will allow the paragraphs to float all the way to the edge of the screen.

```
.top{
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

You would probably also want to change the alignment of the text from center to left.

```
.top p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

If you don't want the paragraphs to align precisely to the right edge of the screen, you could add some padding.

```
.toright {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}
```

You will achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u78EW.png) which scales with the width of the screen.

I am not sure that this is the best solution, but I think you could achieve what you're looking for.

/*------ EDIT ------*/

If you want to align your .top div you could use display: flex; instead, and set the flow to be of type row, this way maragin: 0 auto; will align the div to the center.

```
.top{
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}
```

You will achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw48v.png)

Answer (score -1):

While understanding floats and inline blocks is very important.
I'd also suggest learning flex box.

This is a perfect intro use case.  You'll be able to get what you want to achieve with it very quickly.